Issues to convert Postal code in lat and lng
I'm currently working on converting some postal codes into latitude and longitude coordinates. I've successfully imported the PCCF, but I've run into an issue. The smallest geography unit in the PCCF is the community name, which is more granular than my data requires. This means that a single postal code can correspond to multiple community names, each with its own latitude and longitude, as shown in the attached image.

My question is: Is there an alternative method to calculate the latitude and longitude for each postal code without relying on the community name? For example, can I use a central or average value of the latitudes and longitudes corresponding to the same postal code?
Currently, I've tried the following code without success:
##PCCF
library(data.table)
library(readr)
column_widths <- c(6,3,2,4,7,70,3,3,3,1,7,2,4,5,4,1,8,3,1,11,13,1,1,30,1,1,8,8,1,3,1,1) 

pccf_fwf <- read_fwf("/Users/langbai/Desktop/PCCF_FCCP_V2403_2021.txt", col_positions = fwf_widths(column_widths))

column_names <- c("Postal_code", "FSA", "PR", "CDuid", "CSDuid", "CSDname", "CSDtype", "CCScode", "SAC", "SACtype", "Ctname","ER", "DPL", "FED13iud", "POP_CNTR_RA", "POP_CNTR_RA_type", "PRCDDA", "Dissemination_block", "Rep_Pt_Type", "LAT", "LONG", "SLI","PCtype", "Comm_Name", "DMT", "H_DMT", "Birth_Date", "Ret_Date", "PO", "QI", "Source", "POP_CENTR_RA_SIZE_CLASS")
names(pccf_fwf) <- column_names

Merged Data
pccf_fwf <- pccf_fwf %>%
  mutate(CSDuid = as.character(CSDuid))

matched_data <- shapefile_data %>%
  left_join(pccf_fwf, by = c("CSDUID" = "CSDuid"))

final_merged_data <- matched_data %>%
  left_join(df, by = "Postal_code")

final_data_filtered <- final_merged_data %>%
  filter(!is.na(number_of_farms))%>%
  arrange(desc(number_of_farms))

final_data_frame <- final_data_filtered %>%
  st_set_geometry(NULL) %>%
  as.data.frame()

final_data_filtered_selected <- final_data_frame %>%
  select(CSDUID, CSDNAME, LAT, LONG, number_of_farms, Postal_code) %>%
  distinct()
final_grouped_data <- final_data_filtered_selected %>%
  group_by(Postal_code) 

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!


My question is: Is there an alternative method to calculate the latitude and longitude for each postal code without relying on the community name? For example, can I use a central or average value of the latitudes and longitudes corresponding to the same postal code?

Is more a data representation question than a programming one.
One option is to use simple features (package sf) and calculate the st_convex_hull or st_boundary of your data grouped by postal code
As I only can see a picture of your data I will make an example with that

library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)

# Example
df <- data.frame(
    SDUID = c(1001504L, 1001519L, 1008001L, 1008004L, 1205006L, 1205008L, 
    1205008L, 1205008L, 1205008L, 1205008L), 
    CSDNAME = c("Portugal Cove St Philip's", "St. John's", "Division No. 8, Subd. M", 
    "Lumsden", "Bear River 6B", "Annapolis Royal", "Annapolis Royal", 
    "Annapolis Royal", "Annapolis Royal", "Annapolis Royal"), 
    LAT = c(47.62963, 47.56795, 49.3502, 49.29263, 44.70593, 
    44.7413, 44.74589, 44.74394, 44.74367, 44.74293), LONG = c(-52.83836, 
    -52.7935, -53.72528, -53.59201, -65.50196, -65.51063, -65.51603, 
    -65.51923, -65.5184, -65.5187), number.of.farms = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Postal.code = c("AIM2P6", 
    "AIB3N4", "AOG3EO", "AOG3EO", "BOSIAO", "BOSIAO", "BOSIAO", 
    "BOSIAO", "BOSIAO", "BOSIAO"))

df <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("LONG", "LAT"))

pcode <- df |> 
  group_by(Postal.code) |>
  summarise(area = st_convex_hull(st_combine(geometry)))

pcode
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -65.51923 ymin: 44.70593 xmax: -52.7935 ymax: 49.3502
#> CRS:           NA
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   Postal.code                                                               area
#>   <chr>                                                               <GEOMETRY>
#> 1 AIB3N4                                               POINT (-52.7935 47.56795)
#> 2 AIM2P6                                              POINT (-52.83836 47.62963)
#> 3 AOG3EO                      LINESTRING (-53.72528 49.3502, -53.59201 49.29263)
#> 4 BOSIAO      POLYGON ((-65.50196 44.70593, -65.51923 44.74394, -65.51603 44.74…



Thanks!! This is really helpful. I just got the correct geometry! Thanks a lot!
